How to decode webm / vp9 with transparent background?
I've been fighting with this for a few days now. I have a video that shows with a transparent background in browsers, but I can't emulate this behavior on a native Android device. It also gives me a transparent background when I decode with ffmpeg, but only if I specify -c:v libvpx-vp9 for the input.
Here is it's ffprobe:
ffprobe output_with_alpha_fixed.webm
  libavutil      59. 39.100 / 59. 39.100
  libavcodec     61. 19.100 / 61. 19.100
  libavformat    61.  7.100 / 61.  7.100
  libavdevice    61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavfilter    10.  4.100 / 10.  4.100
  libswscale      8.  3.100 /  8.  3.100
  libswresample   5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libpostproc    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'output_with_alpha_fixed.webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf61.7.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 833 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, unknown/smpte170m/bt709, progressive), 512x512, SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn
      Metadata:
        alpha_mode      : 1
        ENCODER         : Lavc61.19.100 libvpx-vp9
        DURATION        : 00:00:02.000000000

Notes from the ffprobe:

Single stream (no separate alpha stream)
alpha_mode = 1
yuv420p

I'm using libvpx to decode the stream manually. I'll put the code below but tldr is that I'm seeing exactly what ffprobe is indicating above. The webm container only has a single stream. libvpx interprets the stream as YUV, not YUVA.
The frame renders properly, but it's got a black background.
I'm not sure what else to do. How can I decode this with a transparent background like web browsers and ffmpeg is able to?
Here is my log output while decoding:
Tracks: 1
Frame received: 512x512 (bit-depth: 8)
Image format: 0x102
Alpha detected: No
Strides - Y: 576, U: 288, V: 288, Alpha: 576
VPX decoder destroyed

Here is the C code I'm using to decode:
    vpx_codec_ctx_t codec;
    vpx_codec_dec_cfg_t cfg = {0};
    vpx_codec_iface_t* iface = vpx_codec_vp9_dx();

    cfg.threads = 4;  // Enable multi-threading

    if (vpx_codec_dec_init(&codec, iface, &cfg, 0)) {
        LOGE("Failed to initialize VPX decoder");
        return nullptr;
    }

    unsigned int bufferLength = static_cast<unsigned int>(length);
    if (bufferLength == 0) {
        LOGE("Buffer is empty");
        vpx_codec_destroy(&codec);
        return nullptr;
    }

    vpx_codec_err_t decodeStatus = vpx_codec_decode(&codec, buffer, bufferLength, nullptr, 0);
    if (decodeStatus != VPX_CODEC_OK) {
        LOGE("Failed to decode VP9 video. Error: %s", vpx_codec_error(&codec));
        vpx_codec_destroy(&codec);
        return nullptr;
    }

    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = nullptr;
    vpx_image_t* img = vpx_codec_get_frame(&codec, &iter);
    if (img == nullptr) {
        LOGE("No frame received from decoder");
        vpx_codec_destroy(&codec);
        return nullptr;
    }

    LOGI("Frame received: %dx%d (bit-depth: %d)", img->d_w, img->d_h, img->bit_depth);
    LOGI("Image format: 0x%x", img->fmt);

    bool has_alpha = (img->fmt & VPX_IMG_FMT_HAS_ALPHA) != 0;
    LOGI("Alpha detected: %s", has_alpha ? "Yes" : "No");

    int width = img->d_w;
    int height = img->d_h;
    int frameSize = width * height * 4;  // RGBA buffer
    uint8_t* rgba = new uint8_t[frameSize];

    uint8_t* y = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_Y];
    uint8_t* u = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_U];
    uint8_t* v = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_V];
    uint8_t* alpha = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_ALPHA];  // Extract alpha plane

    int y_stride = img->stride[VPX_PLANE_Y];
    int u_stride = img->stride[VPX_PLANE_U];
    int v_stride = img->stride[VPX_PLANE_V];
    int a_stride = img->stride[VPX_PLANE_ALPHA];

    LOGI("Strides - Y: %d, U: %d, V: %d, Alpha: %d", y_stride, u_stride, v_stride, a_stride);

    // YUV to RGBA conversion with alpha handling
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
            int yIndex = j * y_stride + i;
            int uvIndex = (j / 2) * u_stride + (i / 2);

            int Y = y[yIndex];
            int U = u[uvIndex] - 128;
            int V = v[uvIndex] - 128;

            int R = Y + 1.402 * V;
            int G = Y - 0.344 * U - 0.714 * V;
            int B = Y + 1.772 * U;

            R = (R > 255) ? 255 : (R < 0) ? 0 : R;
            G = (G > 255) ? 255 : (G < 0) ? 0 : G;
            B = (B > 255) ? 255 : (B < 0) ? 0 : B;

            int rgbaIndex = (j * width + i) * 4;
            rgba[rgbaIndex + 0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(R);
            rgba[rgbaIndex + 1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(G);
            rgba[rgbaIndex + 2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(B);
            rgba[rgbaIndex + 3] = (alpha) ? alpha[j * a_stride + i] : 255;  // Alpha or fully opaque

        }
    }

    vpx_codec_destroy(&codec);
    LOGI("VPX decoder destroyed");

    jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray(frameSize);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, frameSize, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(rgba));
    delete[] rgba;

